# Javafx FXMLLoader class

Tags: java, javafx

While i am studying Javafx i had already studied the stage , scene and scene graph ( tree data structure )( branch node , leaf node ) etc ...
So i know the basics of the scene graph that it must contain a root node and its children and the scene class takes a parameter of type root node so my question is
when i write this line :

```
FXMLLoader load = new FXMLLoader(getClass.getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

So i know that here i am creating an object of the FXMLLoader so here what is actually going on ? i just wanted to know what happens when i use the FXMLLoader to load my .fxml code ...
Does it create a class without .fxml like the basic way without javafx or CSS ?
Or does this FXMLLoader returns to root node and its children.
In summary i want to know how this FXMLLoader works.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Exception : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
But i really don't care a lot about the error i just wanted to know how the fxmlloader function works and how it loads the controls etc ..

Comment: That's not enough information to diagnose the exception: you need the root cause (post the complete stack trace in the question). If you don't care about it, just delete that part of your question entirely.

Comment: Okay i have edited it also above your comment when i mentioned controls i means the buttons / checkboxs / layouts not the action controls

Comment: How a fxml is interpreted is described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html . If you want to know what exactly happens "under the hood" read the source code or ask a more specific question. That class contains <3500 LOC and explaining everything is more than anyone could accomplish in an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

does just the same as any other similar Java code, it creates an instance of the `FXMLLoader` class. You also set its `location` property to the URL you specify (basically representing the `sample.fxml` resource in the same package as the class you are in). This doesn't load or read the FXML file until you call

```
loader.load();
```

When you do call this, it reads and parses the FXML file, and creates an object hierarchy corresponding to the elements in the FXML. If the FXML specifies a controller, it injects any elements with `fx:id` attributes into `@FXML`-annotated fields in the controller with the same name as the attribute. Once that is complete, it calls the controller's `initialize()` method, if it has one, and finally returns the object corresponding to the root element of the FXML file. This object is also set as the `root` property, so the following code is identical:

```
loader.load();
Parent root = loader.getRoot();
```

and

```
Parent root = loader.load();
```

As an example, suppose your FXML were

```xml
<BorderPane fx:controller="example.Controller">
  <top>
    <Label fx:id="header"/>
  </top>
  <bottom>
    <HBox>
      <children>
        <Button text="OK" fx:id="okButton" />
        <Button text="Cancel" fx:id="cancelButton" />
      </children>
    </HBox>
  </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Then

```
Parent root = loader.load();
```

causes code to be executed that has the exact same effect as executing the following in the loader:

```
public class FXMLLoader {

    // not a real method, but functionally equivalent to the load()
    // method for the example FXML above:
    public BorderPane load() {

        example.Controller controller = new example.Controller();
        this.controller = controller ;
        
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        this.root = borderPane ;
        
        Label header = new Label();
        controller.header = header ;
        borderPane.setTop(header);
        
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        Button okButton = new Button();
        okButton.setText("OK");
        controller.okButton = okButton ;
        hbox.getChildren().add(okButton);
        
        Button cancelButton = new Button();
        cancelButton.setText("Cancel");
        controller.cancelButton = cancelButton ;
        hbox.getChildren().add(cancelButton);
        
        borderPane.setBottom(hbox);
        
        controller.initialize();
        
        return borderPane ;

    }
}
```

Of course, since it's reading the FXML file at runtime, all this is actually done by reflection, but the effect of the code is the same. At no point does any of the actual code above ever exist.

The [Introduction to FXML document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) provides a full specification of the FXML document; obviously there is far too much there to cover everything in a post here.

Comment: What do you mean by it creates object "hierarchy" ?
So in summary it creates the Root node and its children in the memory and then it returns the root node address 
right ?

Comment: For example i have button and its id = "idbutton" 
so in the control class it creates a pointer that points to that button so i can change text and set text ... right ?

Comment: @NewUser It creates objects and sets properties on those objects. Of course, some of  those properties are other objects, etc (so it's just a regular aggregation relationship between objects). E.g. you might have a `BorderPane` as the root element, with a `HBox` as the `top` property, with a couple of `Button`s in the `HBox`. The `FXMLLoader` creates all the actual objects in memory, ties them together by setting properties, and returns a reference to the root element.

Comment: "It creates a pointer" is not really accurate - you, as a programmer, create the reference in the controller class. The `FXMLLoader` sets the value of that reference to the button that it creates corresponding to the `<Button fx:id="idbutton">` element in the FXML file.

Comment: @NewUser There's no real magic here: the `FXMLLoader` really just executes Java code that would be equivalent to what you would get if you just translated the FXML to Java.

Comment: Well since i first started with c++ so i always think about "reference" in java as a pointer and i always say "pointer" instead of "reference" ( i just forget )
but yea reference in java is not a real pointer i just think about it like pointers
"It creates a pointer is not really accurate - you, as a programmer"
I didn't actually understand what you mean

Comment: @NewUser The `FXMLLoader` doesn't *create* the reference. The reference already exists because you create it in code (in the controller). The `FXMLLoader` *sets the value* of the reference.  Anyway, I added an example to the answer which I assume clarifies what is happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot 
Actually from the beginning the answer that i was waiting for that the fxmlload.load function (translate) the fxml code as a normal java code (normal java code = like the example you mentioned above)

Comment: @NewUser It does something functionally equivalent to that; note that it doesn't actually do that translation - so it doesn't automatically generate Java code and compile it (as happens with JSP in a web application, for example). It uses reflection to do the equivalent thing.

Comment: Yea i know that it doesn't actually translate it but for just a clarify meaning the load function load the fxml code as normal java

Comment: @NewUser Just wanted to be sure we were meaning the same thing :).

Comment: My basic language is not English so i didn't get the real meaning of "Accurate"

Comment: @NewUser You're misunderstanding the sentence structure I used. I certainly didn't intend to comment on your programming ability (I don't have enough information to make that judgement anyway). I meant that what you said was not accurate. References (or pointers) are kinds of variables. The programmer creates references. The `FXMLLoader` does not create references. The `FXMLLoader` sets the value of references. (So I was being a bit pedantic, but I teach scientific writing courses, so I have a habit of picking up on linguistic inaccuracies.)

Comment: You could easily say "right" instead of "accurate" :D :)
Anyway thanks a lot :)