# When an FXML file is loaded is it's associated controller also loaded

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I've created a solution for a ScreenController class (A class that's extended by the individual controller classes for each screen), which will handle the baseline screens hierarchy within my application.

In my class, I use a function to add the contents (load) the contents of another FXML file onto the current AnchorPane of the current controller.

My questions are:

1) When the new FXML is loaded, is the class (or rather, the specific controller) the FXML uses also instantiated/loaded?

2) When doing this, if the new FXMl's class is instantiated/loaded, is the previous FXML's class released from memory? or is it still using memory.

Screen transitioning code:

```
public void setScreen(String screen) throws Exception
{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(screen));
    window.getChildren().setAll(root);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand that `FXMLLoader` is not a framework, though it may be used as the foundation of a framework. There's no container that manages instances of the controller classes or the loaded roots. What happens to objects created by the `FXMLLoader` is determined by the application code.

An FXML file is just an XML-formatted text file that describes an object graph. The `FXMLLoader` simply interprets that file and creates said object graph<sup>1</sup>. Of course, the FXML format has some specially added syntax to handle JavaFX specific features (e.g. adding event handlers, binding, etc.).

---

> 1) When the new FXML is loaded, is the class (or rather, the specific controller) the FXML uses also instantiated/loaded?

If you have an `fx:controller` attribute in the root element of the FXML file then yes, a new instance of the specified controller class is created (by default). This is also true of all objects described by the FXML file. In other words, every time you load an FXML file the `FXMLLoader` will return *new instances* of the root and controller. How the controller instance is created can be customized by setting a custom `controllerFactory` on the `FXMLLoader`.

If you don't have an `fx:controller` attribute then either there won't be a controller instance or you need to specify one programmatically. In this case, you provide the controller instance manually.

***Note:** Never share a controller class between different FXML files and never share a controller instance between different loads. Doing so will cause all sorts of confusion and is unnecessarily complex. That said, having a common abstract class may be appropriate, as long as it only has state and behavior common to each and every subclass.*

---

> 2) When doing this, if the new FXMl's class is instantiated/loaded, is the previous FXML's class released from memory? or is it still using memory.

As noted at the start of this answer, an `FXMLLoader` simply interprets an FXML file and creates the appropriate object graph<sup>1</sup>. Once it does this, what happens to the created objects is up to you. As long as the objects are strongly reachable by any thread they won't be garbage collected.

If you're asking what happens if you reuse an `FXMLLoader` instance, I'm not entirely sure as I've never tried that. Suffice to say, I recommend creating a new `FXMLLoader` instance each time you want to load an FXML file (or use the static `load(URL)` method).

---

<sup>1. After creating the object graph, if a controller is present then the `FXMLLoader` will also inject any appropriate fields and "link" all appropriate methods.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer, pretty much answers all of my questions. Uh, as for the single instance being shared, that's not what I think. The ScreenController I speak of is simply the parent class for all the subclasses in the ScreenController hierarchy that have common properties and methods to inherit from, saving space in the individual classes. So when you instantiate a subclass, I'm aware that all you're doing is creating a single object (just with the properties of at least 2 (technically 3 - including object) classes).

Comment: @TrojanTheHorse Put that part of the answer there just in case; some of your wording was ambiguous (to me). Edited that part out.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah apologies aha

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you use the FXMLLoader. There are static and non-static load methods and also methods where you can provide an instance of the controller. It is best to have a look at the various load methods in the FXMLLoader class documentation.

Comment: In the implementation shown, when the FXML class is loaded, does the FXML class then load the java controller that's referenced within it? I've seen on http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/fxml.html#javafx-fxml-example that you can set a controller instance, but must I do this in order to instantiate the controller or will it be handled automatically.

Comment: First of all there is nothing like an FXML class. FXML is just an XML file. I prefer not to use the static load methods because the non-static ones offer more flexibility. A good explanation can be found here in the accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48968476/javafx-fxmlloader-class